# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions, but I am using redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

As stated in the title, I'm getting the error "Actions must be plain objects..." when trying to call an action that returns (dispatch) => { ... }

here is the entire project: https://github.com/bmuk/youtube-dj

here is where I create my store: https://github.com/bmuk/youtube-dj/blob/master/src/index.js

here are my actions: https://github.com/bmuk/youtube-dj/blob/master/src/actions.js

here is the offending container: https://github.com/bmuk/youtube-dj/blob/master/src/containers/NextVideo.js

I realize there are many other questions like this one but I was unable to glean any actionable information from them. I have redux-thunk and I'm using it this way in a different project (it just doesn't use containers like this, I pass actions as a whole to the children components) and it works just fine, even with redux devtools, which is the issue most people are running into with this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the root of your problem or not, but when you're using mapDispatchToProps with the connect method of react-redux, you shouldn't have any reason to also use bindActionCreators. It should work fine to have the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    pushVideo: (video) => dispatch(pushVideo(video))
  };
};
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue I can investigate more deeply, but this will simplify what is going on and make it a bit easier to dig into further.

After further digging...
You do need to get rid of the bindActionCreators call for it to work, but the main issue is the react-inline-grid. If you remove the grid it works. The grid is creating its own store (which doesn't have the thunk middleware) which is then going to conflict with yours since you are connecting to it when you are inside the grid.

Comment: https://github.com/bmuk/youtube-dj/commit/96ea25b799890887c6bf26b9dff8b39d740430b9

I removed the bindActionCreators call and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Yikes, well at least I'm not going crazy. Thank you for helping me out. Now to find a better grid. I keep running into what look like promising grids (especially this [one](https://tsuyoshiwada.github.io/react-stack-grid/#/), which would have been perfect for my work project if I didn't run into documentation issues almost immediately)